# Why can't I step into `return function(){}` as part of a dynamically loaded script?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
return function(callback) {
  console.log(callback.toString())
  SystemJS.import('app/shared/shared.js').then(function(result){
    callbackFunction = callback;
    callback(dashboard);
    main();
  });
}
```

This is loaded as part of a dynamic JS call,

```
  var script_func = new Function('ARGS','kbn','dateMath','_','moment','window','document','$','jQuery', 'services', result.data);
  var script_result = script_func($routeParams, kbn, dateMath, _ , moment, window, document, $, $, services);
```

When I step into `script_func` it brings me to the VM file that's been dynamically loaded for my file - when I try to step into the return statement at the end though, it just skips to the end and returns me to the originating `script_result = script_func()` call.

**Bonus Points**: I don't know if "dynamic" is the right terminology here -- I'm not sure what this is called in JavaScript, and just saw something similar referred to as "dynamic loading". I'd love to be corrected if I'm calling it the wrong thing so I can actually find some tutorials on this :)

Comment: Because the function is returned, not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can step into `script_func(...)` because there's a function call to step into. You cannot step into `return function() { ... }` because no function call is happening on that line.

Analogously, do you expect to be able to step into the assignment `my_func = function() { ... }`? You cannot step into anything there, because there is no call happening there to step into. I'm creating a function object and storing it in `my_func`. I cannot step into the function I've stored in `my_func` until I call it.

In your specific case, a function object is created and stored in `script_result`. If you did `script_result(...)`, you could step into that.

Comment: Thanks! Is it for a similar reason that I can't step into `.then()` from the SystemJS chain?

Comment: @MrDuk That's a little different, a little bit the same. The function passed as an argument to `then` actually runs after the termination of the entire call stack. That is, `script_result` function terminates, and whatever called it terminates, etc. and *then* the `then` callback will run, eventually. It's similar in that you don't call it; the system probably calls it because it's used as an `onload` Ajax callback. Looking around for solutions, it seems like your best bet is to put a breakpoint in the debugger (or a `debugger;` statement in your code) within the function you want to pause on.